# Display page is not appearing after submitting form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using wtforms in flask to take an input value and display it in another page. However, when clicking the submit button, the results page doesn't appear. Infact, nothing happens on clicking the submit button. I want the inputvalue to be taken and displayed on the results page. Tried multiple solutions, but nothing seems to work. Can somebody help?

Pasting the code below:

```
# flask_test.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from wtforms import Form, TextAreaField, validators
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length
import pickle
import sqlite3
import os
import numpy as np
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)

class Formdata(Form):
 inputvalue = TextAreaField('',validators = [DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=120)])
 
@app.route("/", methods= ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = Formdata (request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       inputvalue = request.form['inputvalue']
       if form.validate_on_submit():
          return redirect(url_for('results', data = inputvalue))
       else:
          print("wrong details")
    return render_template('index.html', title = 'Tweet',form=form)


@app.route("/results")
def results(data):
    form = Formdata()
    return render_template('display.html', form = form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



# index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter Input</h1>
    {% from "formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form method = post action="/results"></form>
    <dl>
        {{render_field(form.inputvalue)}}
    </dl>
    <div>
        <input type = submit value = 'Submit' name = 'submit_btn'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


# display.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Displaying Data</h1>
    <p>{{ data }}</p>
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Go back to input</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try to use your code but from the first view, you are doing multiple things wrong

- You are not using CSRF token hidden field so basically `validate_on_submit` will never be true. It would help if you always rendered hidden fields in your form template.
- Instead of redirecting to the other page, you can render display.html inside the form post handler
- Your result handler is completely wrong. Get parameters are handled differently. Parameters of the handler must be also mentioned in the handler URL and do different thing. Finally, you are not using `data` anywhere in the handler so you can't expect to be rendered inside the template. You are trying to instantiate form, but you are not using the `form` inside the template.

Please, start with some known working examples and do one change at a time. You made so many mistakes that this just can't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this way using wtforms in flask

```
app.secret_key = 'development key'
class Formdata(FlaskForm):
    inputvalue = TextAreaField('',validators = [DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=120)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Formdata()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('results', inputvalue=form.inputvalue.data))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
@app.route('/results', methods=['GET'])
def results():
    inputvalue = request.args.get('inputvalue')
    return render_template('display.html', inputvalue=inputvalue)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
#index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Input Form</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div>
           
            {{ form.inputvalue.label(class="form-label") }}
            {{ form.inputvalue(class="form-control") }}
            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
I hope your issue resolved with the help of this code
```